# Groups to show many-to-one relationships

Tags: jasper-reports, report, ireport

I need to create a JasperReport in iReport that lists employees info including degree and certification information.
My query returns all the data I need (i think) but I can't figure out how to do the groups and/or details in IReport so that it displays like I need.

Here is my query:

```
select e.eid, e.first_name, e.last_name, 
       d.degree_date, d.degree_name, 
       c.cert_date, c.cert_name
from employees e, degrees d, certifications c
where e.eid = d.eid
and e.eid = c.eid
```

Here are results:

```
1234, John, Smith, 01/01/2010, MCSE, 4/4/2001, B.S. Information Systems
1234, John, Smith, 01/01/2010, MCSE, 5/5/2004, M.S. Comupter Science
1234, John, Smith, 03/01/2010, CISSP, 4/4/2001, B.S. Information Systems 
1234, John, Smith, 03/01/2010, CISSP, 5/5/2004, M.S. Comupter Science
1235, John, Rolph, 01/01/2010, Pottery Instruction, 6/6/2001, B.A. Fine Arts 
1235, John, Rolph, 01/01/2010, Pottery Instruction, 7/7/2004, M.S. Education
1235, John, Rolph, 03/01/2010, Adv Pottery, 6/6/2001, B.A. Fine Arts
1235, John, Rolph, 03/01/2010, Adv Pottery, 7/7/2004, M.S. Education
```

I need the report to display like this:

```
Employee ID Employee Name
1234    John Smith
        Certifications:
        01/01/2010 MCSE
        03/01/2010 CISSP
        Degrees:
        4/4/2001 B.S. Information Systems
        5/5/2004 M.S. Comupter Science

1235    John Rolph
        Certifications:
        01/01/2010 Pottery Instruction
        03/01/2010 Adv Pottery
        Degrees:
        6/6/2001 B.S. B.A. Fine Arts
        7/7/2004 M.S. Education
```

Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DaDaDom suggested, use one report and two subreports:

#### Report 1 - Person

```
1234    John Smith
```

#### Subreport 1.1 - Certifications

```
        01/01/2010 MCSE
        03/01/2010 CISSP
```

#### Subreport 1.2 - Degrees

```
        4/4/2001 B.S. Information Systems
        5/5/2004 M.S. Comupter Science
```

#### Combined Results

Then:

1. Add a Group band to the main report.
2. `Group By` the employee ID.
3. Include the Certificates subreport in the Group band.
4. Include the Degrees subreport in the Group band.
5. Pass the employee ID from the main report to the subreports.
6. Have each subreport query the requisite information based on the employee ID parameter that they receive.